# Terminating program on an empty string in C

Tags: c, user-input

So, I am very new to C and I am trying to terminate my program on an empty string (when the user presses enter with nothing there) but for some reason it is giving me an infinite loop.

Here is my code:

```
while(input[0] != '\0') {
    if(slot < 27 && slot >= 0) {
        struct LinkedList curr = files[slot];
        if(strcmpci(input, curr.val) == 0) {
            printf("%s, \n", curr.val);
        }

        while(curr.next != NULL) {
            curr = (*(curr.next));
            if(strcmpci(input, curr.val) == 0) {
                printf("%s\n", curr.val);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and everywhere that I have went has told me to end my loop with this format

```
while(____ != '\0') {
}
```

so I am very confused.

Comment: `input` never actually changes inside your loop, so it `input[0] != '\0'` the first time through the loop then it will be the same the second time and the third and the 710143rd time

Answer (score 1):

When the user presses enter they are not entering a NULL character, they are entering a newline. Try checking for `\n`

Comment: I changed the `\0` to a `\n` and it still gives me an infinite loop. Still very confused on why this is happening.

Comment: what does the scanf statement look like

Comment: `scanf("%s", &input);`

Comment: Okay, I will try it now. Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: The above code will work, however if the user does not press enter you will have no access to what they inputted, make sure you record it

Comment: Yes I just noticed that. But now it is not iterating through my linked list and not giving the desired output. :( I will do some debugging.